# how to stop page from refreshing everytime a checkbox is click

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist, page-refresh, autopostback

Okay, as simple as possible, I have a checkboxlist that has autopostback set to true and a OnSelectedIndexChanged. However, every time someone clicks a item in the checkbox, the page refreshes. How do I stop this? I've tried using UpdatedPanel(It kind of work).

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="Regions" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Regions_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Regions" DataValueField="ID">
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

The OnselectedIndexChange displays a div of other checkboxes beside the one checkboxlist.

```
protected void Regions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string select = @"Select Facilities from [BulletinBoard].[DMHSAS\290974].[Facilities] ";

    int[] ctr = new int[9];
    int ctr1 = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    dFacilities.Style.Add("display", "block");
    foreach (ListItem item in Regions.Items)
    {
        //Response.Write(item.Selected);
        if (Regions.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            item.Selected = true;

            CheckBoxList1.Visible = true;
            counter++;
        }
        else if (item.Selected)
        {
            if (select.EndsWith("[Facilities] "))
            {
                select += "where ";
            }
            if (select.EndsWith(") "))
            {
                select += " or ";
            }
            select += " (Reg_ID = " + Regions.SelectedIndex + ") ";

            ctr[ctr1 + 1] = Regions.SelectedIndex;
            item.Selected = false;
            counter++;
            CheckBoxList1.Visible = true;
        }

        ctr1++;
    }
    if (counter == 0)
    {
        CheckBoxList1.Visible = false;
        dFacilities.Style.Add("display", "none");
    }

    ctr1 = 0;
    bool all = false;
    foreach (int counter1 in ctr)
    {
        Regions.Items[counter1].Selected = true;
        if (Regions.Items[0].Selected == true)
            foreach (ListItem item in Regions.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    all = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    all = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        if (all == false)
        {
            Regions.Items[0].Selected = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So does it work with the `UpdatePanel` or not? You haven't shown it anyway.

Comment: OP says using updatepanel it kind of worked!

Comment: `UpdatePanel` simplys masks the page refresh. You're still doing the postback. If you don't want the page refresh, why not set `autopostback` to `false`?

Comment: Using updatePanel, I get the first selectedIndex to work, but clicking on the second and so forth items, it doesn't display the divs like it is suppose to.

Comment: If it doesn't diplay them as desired, what is wrong? How are they displayed?

Comment: setting the autopostback to false doesn't let me display the other divs

Comment: The first index is an all one, so it selects all. The second one displays the divs and checkboxes from a database, and so forth. When I don't have UpdatePanel, the divs displays, but with updatepanel, only the the first index catches, so the divs don't even display at all.

Comment: You're definitely going to need to use UpdatePanels.  It's the only way (that I know of) to get only part of your page to PostBack.  Keep the AutoPostBack set to true and wrap it in an UpdatePanel and set an AsyncPostBackTrigger.

Comment: AsynPostBackTrigger didn't work. Can you please elaborate on AsyncPostBackTrigger and how to implement it in checkboxlist and updatePanels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to really like the classic .NET postback workflow, but rather than continue down the webforms path of trying to hide postbacks, even though you want them because it makes the logic easier, why not just try sidestepping it just this one time? If, as you say, you want to prevent the page refresh (aka the postback) then there are a few things you can do to prevent it entirely.

At the top of your page:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .hideme
  {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript>
  var checkBoxes = document.getElementById("<%= Regions.ClientID %>")
    .getElementsByTagName("input");

  var cbListIDss = [
    "<%= CheckBoxList1.ClientID %>",
    "etc"
  ];

function toggle(i, chkElement)
{
  if (chkElement.type == "checkbox") {
    if (chkElement.checked) {
      var cbElement = document.getElementById(cbListIDss [i]);
      cbElement.className = cbElement.className.replace("hideme", "");
      break;
    }
  }
}

  for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    checkBoxes[i].onClick += toggle(i, checkBoxes[i]);
  }
</script>
```

Edit: Then, in your control, remove these attributes: `OnSelectedIndexChanged="Regions_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"`

I didn't add the code for modifying the `select` variable in your postback method, but that can be done in js as well via a hidden input field.

Alternatively, the reason your update panel is not working is because you have

```
if (Regions.SelectedIndex == 1)
{
    select += " where Reg_ID = 1";
    dFacilities.Style.Add("display", "block");

// note the number at the end of this variable 
    CheckBoxList1.Style.Add("display", "block");
}
if (Regions.SelectedIndex == 2)
{
    select += "where Reg_ID = 2";
    dFacilities.Style.Add("display", "block");

// note the number at the end of this variable 
//   All of these are adding display to CheckBoxList1, 
//   even though it seems like these should be adding 
//   the display property to CheckBoxList2, 3, etc.
    CheckBoxList1.Style.Add("display", "block");
}
```

Comment: note what number at the end? and The JavaScript, didn't stop the flickering(postback) at all.

Comment: Also, even, I've notice that I can only grab the top on selected, so if I have index 3 select and I select index 4, it only grabs index 3 and ignores index 4 until I unclick index 3?